# ActionBar under notification/title bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, zxing, titlebar

I'm having an issue with the ActionBar in my app; In certain scenarios the ActionBar appears to go "under" the notifications/title bar. It's reproducible each time and i can't figure out why it's happening. I use the ZXING application with Intents to scan barcodes and return them to my app, and it's at some point during this process the issue occurs.

I thought it'd be best to show you the issue with pictures.

1: The app home screen, all is normal.

[image: App home screen, no issues]

2: Use the menu item to scan a barcode. This appears as expected.

[image: Scan a product...]

3: The product page for the scanned item appears normal. If i click 'Cancel' however...

[image: Product page, all still normal. Press cancel...]

4: The ActionBar has now gone under the notifications/title bar.

[image: Home screen now shows the ActionBar under the notification/title bar]

The only other mention of a bug such of this (that i can find) is in this GitHub issue for ActionBarSherlock (which i'm using): https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/602

I have checked and i'm not doing anything weird with configChanges as Jake mentions.

This issue is seen on my 4.2.2 device, i'm unable to test on a pre-ICS device unfortunately.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? If it is a custom implementation, it might not be playing well with ABS.

Comment: I am on one of my phones (HTC One) but my other phone (HTC Desire S) is on stock, and they both have the issue.

Comment: I'd also suggest testing the regular ActionBar code (without the support library). You can rule out the support library and/or ABS at that point.

Comment: My app has this issue as well and I'm not using the actionbar library at all. It happens quite frequently when my app returns from another activity (onActivityResult). Would love to find a fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it not getting reset back when you come back from the zxing screen.  In your Activity for "Best Before", try reseting the window flags for fullscreen something like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setSystemUiVisibility(this, View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE /* SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE=0 */);
}



private static void setSystemUiVisibility(final Activity activity, final int newValue){
    if (activity.getWindow() != null){
        View v = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (v != null) {
            try {
                Method methodSetSystemUIVisibility = v.getClass().getMethod("setSystemUiVisibility", int.class);
                methodSetSystemUIVisibility.invoke(v, newValue);
            } catch (Exception noop) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried in both of the possible affected activities, the issue is still present. Interesting idea though!

Comment: try setting fullscreen and then taking it away (I edited the answer)

Comment: :( indeed. Try with this `setSystemUiVisibility` method?

Comment: No change again i'm afraid. Tried in both the Home and Edit activities. I appreciate your persistence however!